# can't multiply by negative one in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
turn=1

swap_turn() {
    turn=$((expr $turn \* -1))
}

echo $turn

swap_turn
```

the output is:

```
1
./program.sh: line 5: expr 1 \* -1: syntax error in expression (error token is "1 \* -1")
```

and I can't figure out the problem. why can't it multiply 1 by -1?

Comment: The operand `-1` isn't the problem; your attempt to call `expr` is.

Comment: `$((...))` and `$(...)` are two different things.

Comment: Or, you have too many parens.  You could use `expr` with `$( expr $turn \* -1 )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are incorrectly combining `$(expr ...)` (command substitution) and `$((...))` (arithmetic substitution); it's one

```
turn=$(expr $turn \* -1)
```

or (preferably) the other

```
turn=$(( turn * -1 ))
```

Comment: Would `((turn = turn * -1))` be an option?

Comment: It would be, but I don't see a reason to use it as a non-standard `bash` extension.

Comment: Both variants in the answer are POSIX, but `expr` is mostly obsolete for anything except regular-expression matching.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought `(( ... ))` was a standard bash thingy. I have GNU Bash myself which supports it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo with Bash you could write `((turn *= -1))`

Comment: @LéaGris Cool! .. but isn't that also a non-standard extension then?

Comment: GNU `bash` is the *only* `bash`. POSIX provides a shell standard that multiple shells (`bash` included) implement. Things like `turn=$(( turn * -1 ))` are portable between POSIX-compliant shells; `((turn = turn * -1))` and `(( turn *= -1 ))` are not.

Comment: Ahh... it's getting clearer now. Thanks :-) Ok, I guess those alternatives would have been ok since the question is tagged bash.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
turn=1

swap_turn() {
    turn=$(( $turn * -1))
}

echo $turn

swap_turn
echo $turn
```

Comment: `$` are not needed in arithmetic expression.

Comment: I like using `$` anyway; if `turn` happens to be undefined, you'll get a nice syntax error when the shell tries to evaluate `$(( * - 1))`. Without the `$`, you silently compute `$(( 0 * -1 ))`.

Comment: …which is why I prefer `set -u` everywhere (in addition to `set -e -o pipefail`). That makes `$` in arithmetic expansion truly unnecessary and catches typos in variable names.